# Action execution failed AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

Situation:
I am trying to deploy CloudFormation through codepipeline.
I have created 2 IAM roles (service role for cloudcommit and cloudformation role to deploy).
When I try to create and deploy, the creation works however deploy fails as error "Action execution failed AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; "

Request help.

Answer (score 2):

One of your roles (the one for cloudformation) is missing SSM permissions. You can add the following IAM policy to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameters",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I facing same issue. Just want to confirm which Role we need to modify and In which account we need to change in ROLE.